# not found: local_setup.bash

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a test workspace. Now i deleted that, because i dont need it anymore.

I had the workspace automatically sourced in my  `~/.bashrc`: `/home/luca/workspace/test_ws/install/setup.bash`. Now i deleted that again from my `~/.bashrc`.

Still when i open a terminal i get this message

```
not found: "/home/luca/workspace/test_ws/install/local_setup.bash"
not found: "/home/luca/workspace/test_ws/install/local_setup.bash"
```

How can i solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408440/not-found:-local_setup.bash/) by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-10-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nils_iseke](https://answers.ros.org/users/120024/nils_iseke/) on 2022-10-25**:
Maybe you also wrote it in your /etc/bash.bashrc file.

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-25**:
i checked `etc/bash.bashrc` file and der is no `source` in there.

**Comment by [nils_iseke](https://answers.ros.org/users/120024/nils_iseke/) on 2022-10-25**:
Hm, ok you could execute `cd ~ && cat .bashrc | grep source`  and  `cd  /etc && cat bash.bashrc | grep source` to see which ROS related files are sourced. I am assuming that you are using the bash shell `echo $SHELL`?

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-25**:
cd ~ && cat .bashrc | grep source

```
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash
source ~/workspace/ros_ur_driver/install/setup.bash
source ~/ws_moveit2/install/setup.bash
source ~/workspace/ros_tutorial/install/setup.bash
source ~/workspace/ur_control/install/setup.bash
```

cd /etc && cat bash.bashrc | grep source

```
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.
```

echo $SHELL

```
/bin/bash
```

**Comment by [nils_iseke](https://answers.ros.org/users/120024/nils_iseke/) on 2022-10-26**:
I would just comment out all the sourcing lines, to see if they are part of the problem.

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-29**:
Right now there is three times the  `not found`.
I commented out the last three sources

```
#source ~/ws_moveit2/install/setup.bash
#source ~/workspace/ros_tutorial/install/setup.bash
#source ~/workspace/ur_control/install/setup.bash
```

then the `not found` disappears. For each source one disappears.

Is there a way the source them without executing the `"/home/luca/workspace/test_ws/install/local_setup.bash"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted the folders `log`, `install` and `build` in the Workspaces which caused the `not found`.
Then i build the packages again and the `not found` was gone.

---

Originally posted by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) with karma: 42 on 2022-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0